How quickly can Zeus get to his destination?
Zeus starts at the origin (0,0) and can make repeated moves of one unit either up, down, left or right, but cannot make a move in the same direction twice in a row.
For example, he cannot move from (0,0) to (1,0) to (2,0).
What is the smallest number of moves that he can make to get to the point (1056,1007)?
Attribution:  2016 Gauss Contest (Grade 8)

First of all

 One has to realise that to reach (1056,x) it requires 1056 right moves minimum to reach that goal. We also need to have a vertical movement in between those moves so we need 1056-1 number of vertical moves. All in all we can at minimum only utilise 2111 moves.

So

 To achieve this we just need a zig zag pattern starting with right then up all the way to (1007,1007) and doing so we get to 2014 moves. Then from there we simply use a right, down, right, up pattern. Using this pattern we need 49 right and 48 vertical moves from there to reach (1056,1007). 2014 + 49 + 48 = 2111.


Under the implied definition of a 2D Grid where one unit = 1, the min number of moves would be

 2111.

I would frame the implied definition as the 2D number set representing l-hand number of strikes on the left (x coordinate) and r-hand strikes on the right(y-coordinate)...and the determination is 'how many single stroke left/right alternating strikes are needed to get to the larger of the 2 numbers'.
In this case where L > R, (L * 2) - 1

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!
